# iOS showing my attachment before body email, sent with Python

Tags: python, email, io

I'm sending emails with Python using `smtplib` library. My email has an HTML body and a PNG file attached. The HTML is in a `MIMEMultipart('mixed')` and my PNG file is in a `MIMEMultipart('alternative')`.

For some reason, iOS native app "Mail" does not show my PNG attached at the end of the email, but at the very beginning and clashing with the body. Gmail and Outlook work fine.

My code is:

```
message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
message["From"] = "XXX"
message["Subject"] = "XXX"
message["To"] = "XXX"
message["Cc"] = "XXX"
message["Bcc"] = "XXX"

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

body = """<div dir="ltr">test</div>"""
msgText = MIMEText(body, 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)
message.attach(msgAlternative)

# Add attachment if required
if self._attachment is not None:
   image = MIMEImage(self._attachment, name='PNGfile.png')
   image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='PNGfile.png')
   image.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', 'ID')
   image.add_header('Content-ID', 'ID')
   message.attach(image)


# Prepare the entire email as string
text = message.as_string()
```

Any idea on how to show the PNG attached at the end of the email on Mail app for iOS, without clashing with the body?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using MIMEMultipart('related') rather than MIMEMultipart('mixed')

Comment: Thanks for your help! Then I only see the attachment, but the email body does not appear anywhere